Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value Mapstruct update
@Mapping(target = "documentType", source = "dto.documentTypeId", qualifiedByName = "UpdateDocumentType")
void update(@MappingTarget MyEntity entity, MyDTO dto);


@Named("UpdateDocumentType")
default MyEntity updateDocumentType(MyEntity entity, MyDTO dto) {
    if (dto.getDocTypeId() == null) {
        entity.setDocumentType(null);
        return entity;
    }

    if (entity.getDocumentType() == null) {
        entity.setDocumentType(new DocType());
        entity.getDocumentType().setId(dto.getDocTypeId());
    }
    return entity;
}

Qualifier error. No method found annotated with @Named#value: [ UpdateDocumentType ].
I want to update the entity but with null support on this Enum. Maybe I wrote the update method incorrectly?

Could you share the imports of your class please so that we can reproduce it? The MapStruct FAQs say that you could accidentally be using javax.inject.Named rather than org.mapstruct.Named https://mapstruct.org/faq/#Why-does-@Named-not-work so we should eliminate that first.

The reason why the updateDocumentType method is not being applied is due to the fact that for MapStruct that method is not an update method. You'll need to use @MappingTarget for MapStruct to be able to use that.
The signature of that method should look like
default MyEntity updateDocumentType(@MappingTarget MyEntity entity, MyDTO dto) 

